# Equation of a plane containing a straight line

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, analytic-geometry

A straight line passes through the points $(1, 2, 3)$ and $(-3, -2, -1)$.

I have calculated the system of equations of this line to be 
$$ x = 1 - t,\, y = 2 - t, \, z = 3 - t $$

> The question I have been asked to solve is to find the equation of the plane containing this line.

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: There are infinitely many planes containing that line.  You need something else to specify it uniquely.

Comment: Would it be possible simply to make up a third point then? The question is followed up by asking if the plane is unique, which is obviously is not.

Comment: You could certainly do that.  I'm a bit surprised though the question would ask for *the* plane containing the line -- I was betting that you just forgot to put that the origin is the third point or something.

Comment: Triple checked. There is definitely no third point!

Comment: I believe you!  Yeah, you could just come up with some arbitrary third point (which is not on your line).  Or an easier way would be to write the equation of your line as $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)-t(1,1,1)$.  Then your plane would have the form $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)-t(1,1,1) + s(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, where $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ is *any* vector that's not in the span of $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: It would be convenient to choose the origin as the third point, giving you the plane parameterized by $t(1,2,3) + t(-3,-2,-1).$ But you can also come up with a single equation for the plane, such as $x - 2y + z = 0.$

Comment: You will have an infinite number of planes.

Answer (score 0):

Since one form
of the equation of a plane is
$ax+by+cz+d = 0$,
you want
$0
=a(1-t)+b(2-t)+c(3-t)+d
=a+b+c+d-t(a+2b+3c)
$.

For this to be true
for all $t$,
you must have
$a+b+c+d=0$
and
$a+2b+3c=0$.

You can choose
any two of these arbitrarily
and determine the others
in terms of those.
For example,
choose $a$ and $b$.
Then
$c = -(a+2b)/3$
and
$d
=-a-b-c
=-a-b+(a+2b)/3
=-(2a+b)/3
$.

You might say
"Hey!
There are *two* free parameters here,
but there should be only *one*,
since all the planes must pass through the line."

This is resolved
by noting that
if all of $a, b, c, $ and $d$
are multiplied by any non-zero real,
the resulting plane
is the same.
We can therefore
adopt some normalization convention,
such as
$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = 1$,
to eliminate this possibility.
This reduces the number of
free parameters from two to one.